# Python 2.7 сравнение списка с числом

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a > 10000000 #True
a < 29 #False
```

При сравнении списка с числом получается что список больше любого числа. Почему вообще определена операция сравнения списка с числом (в Python 3.6 такая операция не определена) и что происходит при этом сравнении?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во второй версии Питона можно сравнивать объекты разных (нечисловых) типов. В этом случае сравнение происходит по имени типа. 
Примеры:

```
print [1] > 1  # 'list' > 'int' - True
print [1] > '1'  # 'list' > 'str' - False
```

Сравнения разных числовых типов происходит по обычным математическим правилам.

> Note that comparing objects of different types is legal. The outcome
>   is deterministic but arbitrary: the types are ordered by their name.
>   Thus, a list is always smaller than a string, a string is always
>   smaller than a tuple, etc. [1] Mixed numeric types are compared
>   according to their numeric value, so 0 equals 0.0, etc

https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types - последний абзац